# Cannot get automac python package to work. Error = import: command not found

Tags: python, macos, testing, gui-testing, pyatom

I'm trying to use the [atomic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/atomac) package. However when I get to the usage steps where it says:

```
>>> import atomac
>>> atomac.launchAppByBundleId('com.apple.Automator')
```

I get this error:

```
-bash: import: command not found
```

I am using python 2.7.5 on Mavericks. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: According to the reported error it seems like you are giving those commands in a bash shell, not a python one. When you run a terminal emulator you should first give "python" command to open a python shell, then you can write that code.

Comment: Awesome! That is exactly what I was missing. It works perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Install atomac using pip:
`pip install pyatomac`